# Duplicated values from Tri-INNER JOIN-Relation packed using GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm supposed to get the following row

```
[id -              gamma             -              omega            ]
[1  - Gamma1, Gamma2, Gamma3, Gamma4 - Omega1, Omega2, Omega3, Omega4]
```

But instead I got the result shown on the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63cf9f/9/0)

If I removed a `SET` and kept `GROUP_CONCAT()` of it, It works properly.

**Why are the relation interacting with each other and make duplicated values?**

SQL:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) AS gamma, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(o.name) AS omega 
FROM alpha a

     #SET A.O.
     INNER JOIN alpha_omega ao ON ao.alpha_id = a.id 
     INNER JOIN omega o ON o.id = ao.omega_id 

     #SET A.G.
     INNER JOIN alpha_gamma ag ON ag.alpha_id = a.id 
     INNER JOIN gamma g ON g.id = ag.gamma_id

WHERE a.id = 1
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3a55/10/0 Not sure what you want to achieve but `DISTINCT` should do the trick.

Comment: @lad2025 oh, but how did it get duplicated from the beginning?

Comment: JOINS thtat does not make any sense to me because I do not know the context

Comment: Do you mean that my JOINs are redundant or The namings makes it confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query consists of two "branches" (gamma and omega): this logic is better represented if you should `group by` separately in the two branches of your `from` tree (and you won't have duplication problems anymore):

```
select a.id,
       g.names as gamma,
       o.names as omega
  from alpha a
       join ( select ao.alpha_id,
                     group_concat(o.name) as names
                from alpha_omega ao
                     join omega o on o.id = ao.omega_id
               group by ao.alpha_id ) o on o.alpha_id = a.id
       join ( select ag.alpha_id,
                     group_concat(g.name) as names
                from alpha_gamma ag
                     join gamma g on g.id = ag.gamma_id
               group by ag.alpha_id ) g on g.alpha_id = a.id
 where a.id = 1
```

Note that in practice you will want to repeat the `where alpha_id = 1` filter in the two subqueries separately (I'd be *very* surprised if a query planner sees that it doesn't need to read all the tables in the subqueries without the extra `where`).

Alternatively, aggregate functions support `distinct` for your use case:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct g.name) AS gamma, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(distinct o.name) AS omega 
  FROM ...
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, But i'm really bothered by Why did it get duplicated in the first place, They're both not related except for the `alpha`_Table, Why would they both affect each other That they require me to use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: split your query in two parts: the `alpha` to `omega` part gives you 4 rows, the `alpha` to `gamma` gives you another 4. Your query is equivalent to a cross join between the two parts (the join condition `alpha_id = 1` is true for all rows), hence 16 rows (before the group by)

Comment: Am I using the `JOIN` falsely to get the rows?

Comment: @Toleo no, the join is ok: it's just that you are joining two 4-row sets. (I edited my answer, see if that makes what's happening more clear)

Comment: I see you added it as `Alternative`, Does that mean that using `DISTCINT` on my original query, Or using  your `branches` method, Have no effect on performance?

Comment: In databases *everything* has an effect on performance :) Jokes aside (but it's true), the two "branches" will probably be quicker (if you repeat the `where` in both) – in general two "small" queries run quicker than a "big" one.

Comment: IMHO the "branches" are more verbose (and thus non-elegant) but also more logically sound (and thus elegant). Also, 3/4 of the times when you see `distinct` in a query, it's an horrible hack that hides flaky logic :)

Comment: Well, That was helpful, Now it became a performance question, I think I'll make another question to see if How does both queries affect the performance overall, Since people was always bashing using `SubQueries `over `JOIN` alone, With index.

Comment: @Toleo Performances depend on the indexes and actual data in your db - `explain` is your friend (that said, if you go the "branch" way with the extra `where`, I do not see how the planner could come up with a stupid execution plan - that is, assuming you have the obvious indexes in place)

Comment: I set my `Indexes` perfectly using `explain`, But what urges me is That the `original query` gets a lot and a lot of duplicated values, Just having 100 value would make it 200, then `distinct` it, That probably has a bad effect on the `Performance` or `RAM`, But in the other side, the `Branches` gets it correctly, So in the original I get 16 values, then distinct it, But in branches i get exactly 8 values.

Comment: I was thinking about this before, But how can I use the `WHERE` clause in it? Is it possible to make the branches use `WHERE ao.alpha_id = a.id`? Or do i have to `join alpha a` on each branch and go with `ao.alpha_id = 1`?

Comment: You should check what `explain` tells you, but I bet you'll have to go with `ao.alpha_id = 1`. Maybe you can use a variable or something? (I don't really know about @variables in mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the correct join (without using `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`):

```
SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(o.name) AS omega  
FROM alpha a
JOIN delta d ON d.alpha_id = a.id 
JOIN omega o ON o.id = d.omega_id 
GROUP BY a.id
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) AS gamma
FROM alpha a
JOIN beta b ON b.alpha_id = a.id 
JOIN gamma g ON g.id = b.gamma_id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

and within one row:

```
SELECT id, MIN(gamma) AS gamma, MIN(omega) AS omega
FROM (
SELECT a.id, NULL AS gamma, GROUP_CONCAT(o.name ORDER BY o.name) AS omega  
  FROM alpha a
  JOIN delta d ON d.alpha_id = a.id 
  JOIN omega o ON o.id = d.omega_id
  GROUP BY a.id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.id, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name ORDER BY g.name) AS gamma, NULL
  FROM alpha a
  JOIN beta b ON b.alpha_id = a.id 
  JOIN gamma g ON g.id = b.gamma_id
  GROUP BY a.id
) sub
GROUP BY id;
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3a55/24/0)**

Comment: I'm trying no to get it all in one row, So I will stay away from first one, In the 2nd one, It seems a bit complicated, But it made two different queries unioned to get the correct `SET`, since it is correct with a single-`SET`, Why would it be better instead of using `DISTINCT`? Also I want to understand why there is Duplicated values from the beginning. Also I updated the fiddle to make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having duplicates is because there are many-to-many relationships between alpha and gamma, and between alpha and omega. Due to this, the duplicates in some of the columns of your association table are transferred to the final result after the joins.

To get rid of the duplicates during aggregation, add a distinct to the group_concat function:

```
SELECT a.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.name) AS gamma, 
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT o.name) AS omega 

FROM alpha a

#SET D.O.
INNER JOIN delta d ON d.alpha_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN omega o ON o.id = d.omega_id 

#SET B.G.
INNER JOIN beta b ON b.alpha_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN gamma g ON g.id = b.gamma_id;
```

For more information see [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)